# Room management program in C#

Tags: c#, oop

The following program aims at reproducing a basic hotel room reservation scheme. After an instance of hotel number is created, by calling the `checkIn()` method, the program checks if there are rooms available, and if so it reserves the room.

However, it doesn't work if, after allocating all the rooms, someone checks out from one room (via `checkOut()` method), e.g. room number 1, and then tries to check in into that room. The issue occurs when `checkIn()` calls `hasRoomsAvailable()` method, which in such a case returns false instead of true, due to the fact that `currentRoomNumber` is 5.

Without changing the time complexity of each method, can somebody suggest how to solve this issue and ideally how to improve the design?

```
using System;

namespace HotelManagement
{
    //Hotel class
    public class Hotel
    {
        private bool[] available;
        private int totalNumberOfRooms;
        private int currentRoomNumber;

        // constructor to set number of rooms
        private Hotel(int totalNumberOfRooms)
        {
            this.totalNumberOfRooms = totalNumberOfRooms;
            available = new bool[totalNumberOfRooms];

            for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfRooms; i++)   
                available[i] = true;
        }

        //Returns true if room is available
        private bool hasRoomsAvailable()
        {
            if (currentRoomNumber < totalNumberOfRooms &&
                available[currentRoomNumber])
                return available[currentRoomNumber];
            else
                return false;
        }

        //Time Complexity: O(1)

        //Checks if there's at least one room available and it reserves it
        private int checkIn()
        {
            if (hasRoomsAvailable())
            {
                available[currentRoomNumber] = false;
                return ++currentRoomNumber;
            }
            else
                return -1;
        }
        //Time Complexity: O(1)

        //Check out method
        private void checkOut(int roomNumber)
        {
            if (roomNumber <= totalNumberOfRooms && roomNumber != -1)
            {
                if (available[roomNumber - 1] == false)
                {
                    available[roomNumber - 1] = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Check out room : {0}", roomNumber);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Check Out : {0}", roomNumber);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect room number : {0}", roomNumber);
        }
        //Time Complexity: O(1)

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create an instance of Hotel with 5 rooms
            Hotel hotel = new Hotel(5);
            int roomNum = -1;

            if (hotel.hasRoomsAvailable())
            {
                roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
                Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

                roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
                Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

                roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
                Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

                roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
                Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

                roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
                Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);
            }

            hotel.checkOut(1);
            roomNum = hotel.checkIn();

            Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

            //pause program output on console
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You change _(increase)_ `currentRoomNumber` when you call `checkIn` but you never change it back in `checkOut`. Now, you could fix that, but I wouldn't recommend this approach. You can make things much cleaner if you create another class called `Room` where your `Hotel` class has a property `List<Room> Rooms` or something, and then the `Room` class has a `bool` property called `Available` in addition to any logic that is related to the room.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed your idea seems very interesting. Could you please formulate it in pseudo code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bool[] available` is enough to find a room which can be checked in. maintaining `currentRoomNumber` creates more difficulties than it is worth.

```
public class Hotel
{
    private bool[] available;
    private int totalNumberOfRooms;        

    // constructor to set number of rooms
    public Hotel(int totalNumberOfRooms)
    {
        this.totalNumberOfRooms = totalNumberOfRooms;
        available = new bool[totalNumberOfRooms];

        for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfRooms; i++)   
            available[i] = true;
    }

    //Returns true if room is available
    public bool hasRoomsAvailable()
    {
        return available.Any(room => room);
    }

    //Time Complexity: O(1)

    //Checks if there's at least one room available and it reserves it
    public int checkIn()
    {
        for(int room = 0; room < totalNumberOfRooms; room++)
        {
            if (available[room])
            {
                available[room] = false;
                return room + 1;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
    //Time Complexity: O(1)

    //Check out method
    public void checkOut(int roomNumber)
    {
        if (roomNumber <= totalNumberOfRooms && roomNumber > 0)
        {
            if (available[roomNumber - 1] == false)
            {
                available[roomNumber - 1] = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Check out room : {0}", roomNumber);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Check Out : {0}", roomNumber);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect room number : {0}", roomNumber);
    }
}
```

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Create an instance of Hotel with 5 rooms
    Hotel hotel = new Hotel(5);
    int roomNum = -1;

    if (hotel.hasRoomsAvailable())
    {
        roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
        Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

        roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
        Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

        roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
        Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

        roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
        Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

        roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
        Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);
    }

    hotel.checkOut(1);
    roomNum = hotel.checkIn();

    Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

---

solution with O(1) complexity which uses Queue to store available rooms:

```
public class Hotel
{
    private Queue<int> rooms;
    private int totalNumberOfRooms;        

    // constructor to set number of rooms
    public Hotel(int totalNumberOfRooms)
    {
        this.totalNumberOfRooms = totalNumberOfRooms;
        rooms = new Queue<int>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalNumberOfRooms; i++)   
            rooms.Enqueue(i);
    }

    //Returns true if room is available
    public bool hasRoomsAvailable()
    {
        return rooms.Count > 0;
    }

    //Time Complexity: O(1)

    //Checks if there's at least one room available and it reserves it
    public int checkIn()
    {
        if (rooms.Count > 0)
            return rooms.Dequeue();

        return -1;
    }
    //Time Complexity: O(1)

    //Check out method
    public void checkOut(int roomNumber)
    {
        if (roomNumber <= totalNumberOfRooms && roomNumber > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Check out room : {0}", roomNumber);
            rooms.Enqueue(roomNumber);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect room number : {0}", roomNumber);
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Create an instance of Hotel with 5 rooms
    Hotel hotel = new Hotel(5);
    int roomNum = -1;

    if (hotel.hasRoomsAvailable())
    {
        roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
        Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

        roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
        Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

        roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
        Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

        roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
        Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

        roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
        Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);
    }

    hotel.checkOut(4);
    hotel.checkOut(2);
    roomNum = hotel.checkIn();
    Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

    roomNum = hotel.checkIn();

    Console.WriteLine("Room Allocated is: {0}", roomNum);

    //pause program output on console
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately in this case the checkIn() method would be O(n) and not O(1), violating the time complexity constraint

Comment: @FunnyBuzer, `currentRoomNumber`is not enough to track available rooms with O(1) complexity. instead of `hotel.checkOut(1);` consider example `checkOut(4); checkOut(2); checkIn(); /*need to iterate array to find currentRoomNumber here*/`

Answer (score 0):

Add condition to check every room for availability while checking in.

need to add reference of namespace **using System.Linq;**

```
private bool hasRoomsAvailable()
    {
        if (currentRoomNumber < totalNumberOfRooms && available[currentRoomNumber])
            return available[currentRoomNumber];
        else if (available.Where(x => x == true).Count() > 0)
        {
            currentRoomNumber = Array.IndexOf(available, available.Where(x => x == true).First());
            return available[currentRoomNumber];
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well you want a code which which doesn't scan the rooms to scale well no matter how many rooms you have.
I would suggest the use of hashset for you room numbers

```
public class Hotel
{
    private HashSet<int> avalibe;
    private HashSet<int> busy;


    //constructor to set number of rooms
    public Hotel(int totalNumberOfRooms)
    {
        avalibe = new HashSet<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= totalNumberOfRooms; i++)
            avalibe.Add(i);
        busy = new HashSet<int>();
    }

    //Returns true if room is available
    public bool hasRoomsAvailable()
    {
        return avalibe.Count > 0;
    }
    //Time Complexity: O(1)

    //Checks if there's at least one room available and it reserves it
    public int checkIn()
    {
        if (hasRoomsAvailable())
        {
            var result = avalibe.First();
            avalibe.Remove(result);
            busy.Add(result);
            return result;
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
    //Time Complexity: O(1)

    //Check out method
    public void checkOut(int roomNumber)
    {
        if (!busy.Contains(roomNumber))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect room number : {0}", roomNumber);
            return;
        }
        busy.Remove(roomNumber);
        avalibe.Add(roomNumber);
    }


}
```